# minishift start --vm-driver xhyve

Tags: openshift, minishift

I'm on a macos box, trying to get openshift to start.

```
minishift v1.3.1+a2d3799
CDK v3.1.0-1
```

> minishift start --vm-driver xhyve

or

> minishift start --vm-driver virtualbox

always results in this error:

> Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'xhyve' hypervisor... E0831
>   12:08:02.405025   25814 start.go:282] Error starting the VM: Error
>   attempting to get plugin server address for RPC: Failed to dial the
>   plugin server in 10s. Retrying.

Both virtualbox and xhyve are installed.

Comment: I'd say don't bother trying to debug/fix this, but rather upgrade to the newest version (yeah, sorry): https://github.com/minishift/minishift/releases

Comment: You are right, updating the release 1.5 fixes the issue.

Comment: Cool. How about you answer the question yourself below and mark it as correct? I'll upvote it then as well ;)

Comment: Done what you suggested.

Comment: Upvoted now but you should also accept your answer as the correct one …

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHausenblas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading minishift to release 1.5 fixed the issue.